# Modifying Values in Oracle 19c INSERT Statements

Tags: oracle19c

I'm working with Oracle 19c, and I have a set of 300 INSERT statements in SQL that I need to modify. Specifically, I want to change the values of the IDCATEG column in these statements to be random values between 101 and 200.

The INSERT statements look like this:

```
Insert into PRODUITS
  (IDPRODUIT, DESIGNATION, IDFOUR, IDCATEG, PRIXUNITAIRE,
   UNITESENSTOCK, UNITESCOMMANDEES, NIVEAUREAPPROVISIONNEMENT,
   INDISPONIBLE
  ) values (
    '1','aer','25','83','15,647','897','613','13','0'
  );
```

I need to replace IDCATEG with random values between 101 and 200 for all 300 INSERT statements. Doing this manually is not practical.
Is there a way to achieve this modification programmatically, perhaps by using Oracle 19c's features ?

i tried a code in python from CHATGPT to replace all values of IDCATEG by random values between 101 and 200 but it didn't work
i wanna an SQL command to slove the probleme .. like when we use ALTER SESSION ... to replace "," by "."

Comment: Replacing them in your script probably makes sense, but if you really want to do it on the database side, can you just update them after you've inserted? Or failing than, modify them during the insert with a trigger? It's unclear is this is a one-off thing or you need to repeat it, or if there is existing data, or why you can't change your script. (Also why do you appear to have numeric values in quotes?)